# How many bytes of the random input are actually read by Openssl for the genrsa command?

Tags: random, openssl, rsa

If random.rnd is 5 megabytes of data, how much of that file does the command

> openssl genrsa -rand random.rnd -out privkey.pem 2048

actually read and use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will read and use  all of it. A random file of 5MB is probably much more than need (provided it's really random) for a 2048 bit RSA key. You need 2048 bits (2 times 1024 bits) of entropy, which mean 256 bytes. Depending on the quality of you random source you might want to increase that number.

For fun, [Dilbert has a story on the topic](http://dilbert.com/strips/comic/2001-10-25/).

Comment: ﹢1 for Dilbert comic